# How to send an HTML table,which is created dynamically using javascript,to a another page(servlet,jsp etc)?

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, servlets

How to send an HTML table, which is created dynamically using javascript, to a another page (servlet,jsp etc)?

My Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function createTable(numberOfRows) {
    for ( var i = 1; i < numberOfRows; i++) {
        var tr = document.createElement("tr");
        var tableData = ['hello','world','hi','bye'];
        for ( var j = 0; j < tableData.length; j++) {
            var td = document.createElement("td");
            var data = document.createTextNode(tableData[j]);
            td.appendChild(data);
            tr.appendChild(td);
        }
        document.getElementById("table1").appendChild(tr);
    }
}
function sendTableToAnotherPage(){
// **what should be the code here,to fetch the table created using above function
//and send it to servlet or jsp page via AJAX.**
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
        <table id="table1">
        </table>
<button type="button" onclick="createTable(5)">Create Table</button>
<input type="button" value="Save" onclick="sendTableToAnotherPage()">
</body>
</html>
```

I am facing difficulty in fetching the table data from my servlet/jsp page.
Any help, would be highly appreciated.

Comment: you can include the this table page right instead of sending ? using @include

Comment: Send table data as JSON instead

Comment: @susheel I,didn't get you.

Comment: you can save the entire table as string and retrieve and use wherever u wish to

Comment: @EshaJain how??..could you explain

Answer (score 0):

If table and data is same then, you can pass table.innerHTML to another page.
example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function createTable(numberOfRows) {
    for ( var i = 1; i < numberOfRows; i++) {
        var tr = document.createElement("tr");
        var tableData = ['hello','world','hi','bye'];
        for ( var j = 0; j < tableData.length; j++) {
            var td = document.createElement("td");
            var data = document.createTextNode(tableData[j]);
            td.appendChild(data);
            tr.appendChild(td);
        }
        document.getElementById("table1").appendChild(tr);
    }
}
function sendTableToAnotherPage(){
    document.getElementById("table2").innerHTML = document.getElementById("table1").innerHTML;
}
</script>
         <table id="table2" border="2">

        </table>
        <table id="table1">
        </table>
<button type="button" onclick="createTable(5)">Create Table</button>
<input type="button" value="Save" onclick="sendTableToAnotherPage()">
```

Comment: call serlvet/url with parameter=innerHtmlValue... set it again in next page

Comment: could you explain further?

Comment: Hitesh, for any HTML Object you can get InnerHTML as Text... If your table is "TABLE1" then document.getElementById("TABLE1").innerHTML

Comment: Once you get this text,pass it to another page

Comment: to pass it another serlvet append to URL and launch... http://URL?text=innerHTMLText

Comment: My table has textbox, and below table there is a button, onclick button,i want to display the value entered in the textbox, in an alert box or set in any variable in  javascript. But it shows blank.I tried the following
- alert(document.getElementById('textBoxID').value),
- alert(document.getElementById('textBoxID').innerHTML),
- alert(document.getElementById('textBoxID').innerText)

Comment: <input id="Hello" type="text"/>
 <input id="GetVALUE" type="button" value="GetValue" onclick="alert(document.getElementById('Hello').value);"/>